# How to uninstall ns3 from ubuntu when package can't be located?

Tags: uninstallation, ns-3

I've downloaded ns3.36 via tarball  on ubuntu 20.04.4. But then I confronted some errors while trying to configure it so I decided to uninstall and re-install it again.
I used

```
sudo apt-get remove ns3
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ns3
```

but I got an error:

```
 E: Unable to locate package ns3
```

I've tried doing the same on the different directories from where I've installed like *ns-allinone-3.36* or *ns-3.36* but I'd get the same error.
I've also tried typing ns-3.36 instead of ns3 but still didn't work.

I also tried using dpkg but I got another error:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove ns3 which isn't installed
```

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *install* ns-3 on your computer via the tarball. You simply unpacked the tarball, so `apt` does not know about ns-3. To delete ns-3, just delete the ns-3 directory:

```bash
rm -r ns-allinone-3.36/
```